# How to use NLog to write to different file according to parameter

Tags: nlog

I want to be able to write to logs to a different log file according to one of my log parameters.

Lets say, bankId. Each day and bank will write to their own file like

```
2019-11-11-bank11.log
2019-11-12-bank11.log
```

and so on.

How can i achieve that programmatic with some kind of a pattern for the log file.
I don't want to create a new version of my app every time I have a new bankid.

Comment: programmatic in c# I assume?

Answer (score 0):

You could set [the context in one of the context classes](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/context) and render it with a layout renderer.

e.g. use `${mdlc}` and `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext`:

Config:

```xml
 <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
         fileName="${basedir}/${mdlc:bankid}.log"  .. />
```

Code:

```cs
using (NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("bankid", "bank11"))
{
   logger.Info("myLogEvent");
}
```

See also [all context layout renderers](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=context)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an application-wide setting. For that you should either use:

- NLog Config Variables - `${var:bankid}`
- Global Diagnostic Context - `${gdc:bankid}`

I prefer to use the GDC has it has a minimum number of surprises, when modifying at runtime.

You can do this in NLog.config:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
         fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}-bank${gdc:bankid:whenEmpty=0}.log"  .. />
```

Then at application startup then you can do this:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("bankid","11");
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer

You can also extract a setting from config-file:

- app.config - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer
- appsettings.json - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer